# Is there a way to reference a preceding CTE in the CTE that follows in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, psql

Working in PostgreSQL, I intend to use the output of a CTE as a reference to join another CTE below it.

I've used this style countless times in SQL Server and Synapse, however I'm finding it difficult to replicate in PostgreSQL.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE_mst_rv_prod AS (
    --CTE to answer the product with highest review
        SELECT product_id, COUNT(review) "total_reviews", 
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(review) DESC) "Rank"
        FROM public.reviews
        GROUP BY product_id
        ORDER BY RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(review) DESC)
        LIMIT 1
    ),
    CTE_pd_or_dt AS (
    --CTE to answer the day product was ordered the most
        SELECT P.product_id, O.order_date "MOST_ORDERED_DAY", COUNT(order_id) AS "COUNT_OF_ORDERS"
        FROM CTE_mst_rv_prod P
        JOIN public.orders O ON P.product_id = O.product_id
        GROUP BY P.product_id, O.order_date
        ORDER BY COUNT(order_id) DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ),
    CTE_or_dt AS(--here's the CTE that's unable to use column from the CTE above it
    --CTE to answer if d day with highest order is a public holiday or not
        SELECT D.calendar_dt AS "MOST_ORDERED_DAY",
            CASE 
                WHEN D.day_of_the_week_num IN (1,5) AND working_day = false THEN TRUE
                ELSE FALSE
            END is_public_holiday
        FROM CTE_pd_or_dt 
        INNER JOIN public.dim_dates D ON
        CTE_pd_or_dt.MOST_ORDERED_DAY = D.calendar_dt
    ),
    --CTE to answer the timeliness problem
    CTE_shp_cond AS(
    SELECT O.order_date, O.product_id, S.shipment_date, S.delivery_date,
        O.order_id, CASE WHEN S.shipment_date - O.order_date >= 6 AND
        delivery_date ISNULL THEN 'late' ELSE 'early'
        END "shipment_condition"
    FROM public.orders O
    JOIN public.shipments_deliveries S ON S.order_id = O.order_id
    JOIN CTE_mst_rv_prod RV ON O.product_id = RV.product_id
    )
    
SELECT A.product_id, B.MOST_ORDERED_DAY, C.is_public_holiday, A.total_reviews,

    (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.00)/ top_product.total_reviews, 4)
     FROM public.reviews AS r2 
     JOIN CTE_mst_rv_prod "mrp" ON mrp.product_id = r2.product_id
     WHERE r2.review = 1) AS "pct_one_star_review",
     
     (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.00)/ top_product.total_reviews, 4)
     FROM public.reviews AS r2
     JOIN CTE_mst_rv_prod "mrp" ON mrp.product_id = r2.product_id
     WHERE r2.review = 2)   AS pct_two_star_review,
     
     (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.00)/ top_product.total_reviews, 4)
     FROM public.reviews AS r2
     JOIN CTE_mst_rv_prod "mrp" ON mrp.product_id = r2.product_id
     WHERE r2.review = 3)   AS pct_three_star_review,
     
     (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.00)/ top_product.total_reviews, 4)
     FROM public.reviews AS r2
     JOIN CTE_mst_rv_prod "mrp" ON mrp.product_id = r2.product_id
     WHERE r2.review = 4)   AS pct_four_star_review,
     
     (SELECT ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.00)/ top_product.total_reviews, 4)
     FROM public.reviews AS r2
     JOIN CTE_mst_rv_prod "mrp" ON mrp.product_id = r2.product_id
     WHERE r2.review = 5)   AS pct_five_star_review

FROM CTE_mst_rv_prod A
LEFT JOIN CTE_pd_or_dt B ON A.product_id = B.product_id
LEFT JOIN CTE_or_dt C ON C.order_date = B.MOST_ORDERED_DAY
```

Here's my error message:

> ERROR: column cte_pd_or_dt.most_ordered_day does not exist
> LINE 28:   CTE_pd_or_dt.MOST_ORDERED_DAY = D.calendar_dt
> ^
>
> SQL state: 42703
> Character: 950

I'm working in PostgreSQL and this is a real stress.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! I.e. remove as much as possible and still having the error. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the error message uses a lowercase name even though you specified UPPERCASE.

> ```
> ERROR: column cte_pd_or_dt.most_ordered_day does not exist 
> LINE 28: CTE_pd_or_dt.MOST_ORDERED_DAY = D.calendar_dt 
>                       ^
> ```

[Quoting the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case.

If you look close enough, that's exactly what you missed in the CTE that fails, in the `INNER JOIN...ON` condition:

```sql
CTE_or_dt AS(--here's the CTE that's unable to use column from the CTE above it
--CTE to answer if d day with highest order is a public holiday or not
    SELECT D.calendar_dt AS "MOST_ORDERED_DAY",
        CASE 
            WHEN D.day_of_the_week_num IN (1,5) AND working_day = false THEN TRUE
            ELSE FALSE
        END is_public_holiday
    FROM CTE_pd_or_dt 
    INNER JOIN public.dim_dates D ON
    CTE_pd_or_dt.MOST_ORDERED_DAY --it's UPPERCASE but the double quotes are missing
                                  = D.calendar_dt
),
```

Anytime you feel like using UPPERCASE in an alias/identifier, remember you'll have to double quote it then and there, as well as anytime you want to reference it later. And anytime you or anyone else forgets that, or uses a tool that auto-quotes, or auto-quotes after applying pre-configured PascalCase, camelCase, snake_case, UPPERCASE or anything other than lowercase PostgreSQL defaults to, it won't match the unquoted stuff.

Answer (score -2):

I've been able to fix it, the issue is because in postgresql, CTE aliases are only available in that primary block, so when I do my join based on the initial column name the error disappear and the join work.

Comment: You're not showing what you mean specifically, but if that's what solved it for you, remember that if switching the column used in the `join` condition to `product_id` worked, it's because `product_id` was already lowercase, and thus the same before and after [folding to lowercase due to lack of double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77933636/5298879). Which is not the case for `"MOST_ORDERED_DAY"` you defined with the double quotes first, then referenced as `MOST_ORDERED_DAY` without them, which got folded to `most_ordered_day`, leading to the mismatch.